# Ошибка БД при установке MODx

Tags: mysql, modx

Пытаюсь связать базу данных и MODx, но вылазит такая ошибка. В чем может быть проблема? В интернете нет особо информации про это, в правильности пароля и логина я более чем уверен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, что в конфигурационном файле подключения к базе данных указана кодировка в корректном формате. По крайней мере, в присланной Вами ошибке говорится об этом.

Например, в некоторых случаях может помочь:

`utf-8` => `utf8`

и так далее.